# Finding the angle given the scalar product and magnitude of vector product

Tags: vectors

I've been having difficulty with this problem for a while now. I'm given the following:

- Scalar product of vectors A & B = -3
- Magnitude of Vector product of A & B = 3

I'm now asked to find the angle between the two vectors

Notice that I don't have the components of each vector. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lengths of your two vectors are $x$ and $y$ and the angle between them is $\theta$, then you're given the scalar product, which is $xy\cos\theta$, and the magnitude of the vector product, which is $xy|\sin\theta|$. Adding the squares of these and remembering that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, you obtain $(xy)^2$. So you can find $xy$ and thence $\cos\theta$.

Comment: My answer is intended to handle general questions of this sort. For the particular numerical values in your problem, the fact that the scalar product is the negative of the vector product's magnitude means that $\cos\theta=-|\sin\theta|$ and therefore $\theta=3\pi/4$ "by inspection".